# How to properly generate a Flux from a function that supplies a Mono?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I want to write a piece of code that would iterate over a database reactively (the next query depends on the result of a previous query).

My question could be simplified as follows:
Lets say we have a function like this

```java
// some long running call
private Mono<Integer> calculateNext(Integer value) {
    return Mono.defer(() -> Mono.just(value + 1))
        .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(1L));
}
```

How to make a Flux out of it that would contain the results of repeatedly calling the function?

The following works

```java
Flux.generate(
    () -> Mono.just(0),
    (previousResult, sink) -> {
        var nextResult = calculateNext(previousResult.block());
        sink.next(nextResult);
        return nextResult;
    }
).flatMap(it -> (Mono<Integer>) it)
.takeUntil(it -> it > 1000)
.doOnNext(it -> LOG.info("it = " + it))
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
.blockLast();
```

and produces increasing integers from 1 to 1000.

But it seems like using `.block()` defeats the purpose of using Fluxes and Monos and might lead to performance issues.

This

```java
(previousResult, sink) -> {
    var nextResult = previousResult.flatMap(it -> calculateNext(it));
    sink.next(nextResult);
    return nextResult;
}
```

also works, but seems kinda scary as it appears to be equivalent to chaining a thousand of `.flatMap` calls.

Comment: You used `var`.

Comment: @K.Nicholas Is it a considered unethical? :) My teammates adopted it after switching to java 11, seems convenient.

Comment: Mr. T said it best. "You fools"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Mono.expand` to fetch results recursively and use the result of a previous query to retrieve next results.

```
private Flux<Integer> fetch(int start, int end) {
    return calculateNext(start)
            .expand(res -> calculateNext(res))
            .takeUntil(res -> res == end);
}

@Test
void test() {
    StepVerifier.create(fetch(0, 5))
            .expectNext(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
            .verifyComplete();
}
```